# How to add element into array on php recursive loop?

Tags: php

```
function test_loop($x_values,$x, $y)
{
    $x = $x + 1;
    if($x < 10)
    {
         $x_values[] = $x."#"; // insert item 2#,3#,4# into array
    }

    //loop again if y is not = 3;
    $y = $y + 1;
    if($y < 5)
    {
        test_loop($x_values, $x, $y); 
    }

    return $x_values; 
}

function abc(){
    $bababa = test_loop([],1,0);

    foreach($bababa as $fpackage_id)
    {
        echo $fpackage_id;
    }
}

abc();
```

Output :

```
2#
```

How to make the output become :

```
2#,3#,4#
```

Comment: turn `$x_values` as static var:https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static

Comment: i have pass $x_values into function argument, do i really still need to declare it as static / public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> if($y < 5)
>     {
>         test_loop($x_values, $x, $y); 
>     }
> ```

You're not doing anything with the return value of the recursive function call.
You need to add the array returned from `test_loop()` to the existing array:

```
$x_values += test_loop($x_values, $x, $y);
```

Your code now prints: `2#3#4#5#6#`

If you want the output to be `2#, 3#, 4#, 5#, 6#`, you can use the [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode) function instead of a loop:

```
echo implode (', ', $bababa);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to utilize pass by reference:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

I haven't looked too closely at your code, you may need to make more changes than this... but this might work:

```
function test_loop(&$x_values,$x, $y)
{
    $x = $x + 1;
    if($x < 10)
    {
         $x_values[] = $x."#"; // insert item 2#,3#,4# into array
    }

    //loop again if y is not = 3;
    $y = $y + 1;
    if($y < 5)
    {
        test_loop($x_values, $x, $y); 
    }

    return $x_values; 
}

function abc(){
    $bababa = test_loop([],1,0);

    foreach($bababa as $fpackage_id)
    {
        echo $fpackage_id;
    }
}

abc();
```

Comment: read the documentation, it shows "PHP 5.4.0, call-time pass-by-reference was removed, so using it will raise a fatal error."

Comment: whoops, it's been a really long since I've used php! :-S

Answer (score 0):

You should use array_push() function to add an element in the array

[Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

```
    if($x < 10)
    {
         array_push($x_values,$x.'#');
    }
```